# Problems with $_POST

Tags: php

I'm having problems passing data from a form, I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. I have modeled my page on one that works but mine does not function.

I want to check I have the general structure right. I have stripped it right down and it still wont work.

```
<?php
    define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
    include 'php/functions.php';

    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    logThis('ready!');  

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {       
        logThis('success'); 
    }
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the whole page now, I have commented everything else out. 
`logThis()` works i get the `'ready!'` in the log but no `'success'` message when ever i press the submit button.

Comment: _"but it's not working"_  Does it catch fire or what?

Comment: $_POST needs input name.

Comment: @frz3993: Answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my bad english!

In PHP, `$_POST` expect the **name of input field**, not the id.
So you need to set names to your fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="villainClass" name="villainClass" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="heroClass" name="heroClass" value="" />
```

Comment: I added the name tags but it still wont work, I have stripped it down even further and still having the issues

Answer (score 1):

**Modify your HTML code**

**You can get posted data only by the name of input field**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{
$username = $_POST["username"];
echo $username;
}

?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the name tags but it still wont work, I have stripped it down even further and still having the issues

Comment: added the input, still wont register the submit

Comment: https://github.com/Vooders/HGT/blob/master/newGame.php I've just changed the name of the submit button to `newG` to test a theory