# Using forms from a tabbed index page

Tags: php

So I'm new to PHP and I'm having trouble getting some of my forms to function. I think it may be the way my site is set up that's causing me problems.

I have index.php which is set up as such:

```
<div class="pageContent">
<div id="main" style="width:1000px; margin:0 auto;">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <div id="tabs" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-0">Overview</a></li>      
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Ranked</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Arena</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Decks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">New Game</a></li>     
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Admin</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-0"></div>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div id="tabs-2"></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"></div>
        <div id="tabs-4"></div> 
        <div id="tabs-5"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Load the pages into tabs -->
    <script>
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#tabs-0").load("tab0.php");
        $("#tabs-1").load("tab1.php");
        $("#tabs-2").load("tab2.php");
        $("#tabs-3").load("tab3.php");
        $("#tabs-4").load("newGame.php");
        $("#tabs-5").load("admin.php");
    </script>
</div><!-- / main -->
</div><!-- / pageContent -->
```

This gives me a nice static page and 6 tabs of `.php` files to do cool stuff on.

There are a couple of forms, log in and such, in `index.php` which all function fine. But when I create a form on a page in a tab, it will not.

Here's an example from `admin.php` (`#tabs-5`)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delLog'])){
    unlink('log.txt');
    echo 'Success';
}
if(isset($_POST['delLog'])){
    unlink('error_log');
    echo 'Success';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="40%" valign="top"> 
    </td>
    <td width="30%" valign="top">
    <h1>error_log</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="delErr" id="delErr" value="Delete" />
        </form>
        <hr />
    <?php       
        $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('error_log'));
        foreach ($lines as $line){
            echo $line.'<br>';
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="3'0%" valign="top">
    <h1>log.txt</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="delLog" id="delLog" value="Delete" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <?php   
        $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('log.txt'));
        foreach ($lines as $line){
            echo $line.'<br>';
        }
    ?>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is another, better example. A stripped down test I did yesterday for this question

[Problems with $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276803/problems-with-post)

```
<?php
    define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
    include 'php/functions.php';

    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    logThis('ready!');  

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {       
        logThis('success'); 
    }
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Neither of these examples work. When the submit button is pressed the site refreshes but no PHP actions are taking place. There is no error message in error_log. I don't think it's getting the call at all.

Neither of the forms return an output, one adds to the database. The other deletes log files.

Hope I've provided enough details.

Comment: @waders there is no real output actually one adds entries to the database and the other deletes log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What ever you are trying to do is not possible at all. You can not load PHP code to frontend, it can only be processed by the server.**

**The statement `$("#tabs-5").load("admin.php");` is fetching only the html code (processed by the server) not the PHP script**

Comment: OK so no forms in pages then. just use them to display results

Comment: you can use forms in pages but the script, to which you are submitting your form should be on the index file (in your case) or outside as a different script file

Comment: Yes, sorry, I understand. I meant to type 'OK so no php in pages...' thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="" method="post">` will post to the current page (ie. whatever is in your address bar).

When you load the pages into `index.php` using ajax, that means the forms will post to `index.php`... I'm guessing you are expecting to fetch the form submissions in each individual php-file

So to fix it either you have to also post using ajax (and refresh the tabs with the response), or you need to change the `action` attribute on the forms to each individual php-file... in which case you lose your tabbed layout when a form is submitted. You can work around that as follows:

In each of the php-files you do something like this (using `newGame.php` as example):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Do your form-handling stuff first
    // [...]

    // ...and then redirect back to index.php
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
} else {
    //Print your form
    echo '<form action="newGame.php" method="post">';
    // [...]
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Create game">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

- Note that there should be no `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` or other `html` in the "sub-pages" at all - just the bare content you want inside the tabs...

Now for the **ajax-submit** method you should also remove all "wrapping html", you should still set a `target="[...]"` on each form, and you should still do form handling inside each individual file. But you should not do a redirect after form handling, but just output the form again:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Do your form-handling stuff first
    // [...]

    //Maybe print a little message to let the user know something happened
    echo 'Form completed at ' . date('H:i:s');
}
//...then print your form no matter what
echo '<form action="newGame.php" method="post">';
// [...]
echo '<input type="submit" value="Create game">';
echo '</form>';
```

Then add this script to `index.php` - it will post all forms inside the tabs using ajax instead of refreshing the page:

```
<script>
    my_cool_ajax_post = function(form_elm, tab_elm) {
        //Actual ajax post
        $.post(form_elm.target, $(form_elm).serialize(), function(data){
            //Results are in, replace tab content
            tab_elm.html(data);
        });
    };
    $(document).on("submit", "#tabs form", function(){
        //Store the form element
        var form_elm = this;
        //Find the parent tab element
        var tab_elm = $(this).closest('#tabs > div');
        //Really simple "loader"
        tab_elm.html('<p>loading...</p>');
        //Submit by ajax
        my_cool_ajax_post(form_elm, tab_elm);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

*Disclaimer:* Completely untested, so let me know...

Comment: That was the plan to have each file handle it's own form. Does this mean   `index.php`  can handle all forms from all pages?

Comment: Yes, that would work... but it will probably be a mess to maintain.

Comment: @Mikk3IRo OK so if I understand you. I point the forms to themselves i.e `action="admin.php"` for the form in `admin.php`. then add the method you posted to the page to bring back the tabbed layout?

Comment: @KevWilson - correct, that will work and be easier to maintain (I've updated my answer). It is not as elegant as posting by ajax just like you fetch by ajax though - that will allow you to keep whatever tab is already open, scroll position and so on. If you hang on I think I can make an example of that too...

Comment: @Mikk3IRo That would be awesome thanks! I'll go make a brew

Comment: Oh - actually that other answer that just popped up highlights a major misunderstanding in what you are doing, that I completely missed... you shouldn't have `<head>`, `<body>` etc. in your "included" php-files at all if you load them by ajax.

Comment: @Mikk3IRo OK so no forms in pages then. just use them to display results

Comment: I didn't say no forms, php, scripts, html or whatever in pages... use any of those as you please, I just said no "extra html" - only output the html that goes inside the tabs (as if you wrote it directly inside your `<div id="tabs-0"></div>` tag - you wouldn't put a `<head>` tag in there if you did, and you shouldn't put a `<head>` tag in there when you load by ajax). It took some time to complete my answer, but both methods should be valid, and I'm pretty sure the answer makes sense as a whole too (now)...